# How to display feedback message when data is null

Tags: laravel

I have this controller in Laravel-5.8:

```
public function index()
{
    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('is_current', 1)->first();  
     
    $currentstatus = Goal::select('is_approved')->where('identity_id', $identities->id)->first();
    $goalsettingstatus = Parameter::select('activate_goal_setting')>first();

    $goals = Goal::where('identity_id', $identities->id)->where('is_visible', 1)->where('is_special_project', 0)->whereNull('deleted_at')->get();
 
    return view('student.goals.index')->with(['goals' => $goals])
            ->with('currentstatus', $currentstatus)
            ->with('goalsettingstatus', $goalsettingstatus);
}
```

It happens that there is no data for $identities. It is null, and this makes it to throw error at this line $currentstatus

How do I make Laravel to display feedback message that data is not available instead of the error page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return,  if `$identities` is null :

```
public function index()
{
    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('is_current', 1)->first();  
     
    if($identities->isEmpty()) {
        return view('student.goals.index')->with(['error-message' => 'No data found!!!']);
    }

    $currentstatus = Goal::select('is_approved')->where('identity_id', $identities->id)->first();
    $goalsettingstatus = Parameter::select('activate_goal_setting')>first();

    $goals = Goal::where('identity_id', $identities->id)->where('is_visible', 1)->where('is_special_project', 0)->whereNull('deleted_at')->get();
 
    return view('student.goals.index')->with(['goals' => $goals])
            ->with('currentstatus', $currentstatus)
            ->with('goalsettingstatus', $goalsettingstatus);
}
```